# amazon lex showing invalid response

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-lex

Facing Problem in lex.Written code in lambda for question and answer getting answer from the database to the lambda function perfectly but the amazon lex is showing invalid response Received error response from Lambda: Unhandled.

but everything written in the code showing correct answer my config file

```
{
"currentIntent": {
"slots": {
  "Name": "ramya",
  "Hi": "What is your given/family name?"
 },
 "name": "Firstone",
 "confirmationStatus": "None"
 },
 "bot": {
 "alias": "$LATEST",
 "version": "$LATEST",
 "name": "Ramya"
 },
 "userId": "John",
 "invocationSource": "DialogCodeHook",
 "outputDialogMode": "Text",
 "messageVersion": "1.0",
 "sessionAttributes": {}
 }
```

Help me out
Thanks in advance

Comment: post your Lambda code as well

Comment: I will gmail uu my code please check there

Comment: i would suggest you to put your code here so that people other than me can help you. if there is some sensitive information, you should remove that.

Comment: It is confidential  for my upcoming project.so i mailed u my whole code if it is ok help me out.